# Cartesian plane in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How to make Matlab draw a plane like this? Can't find the settings for `plot` command in documentation. Maybe there is another command for planes like this?

[image]

Comment: You must see these links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38186859/how-to-set-the-origin-to-the-center-of-the-axes-in-matlab,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using MATLAB 2015b and higher, check the option of `AxisLocation`.

```
figure
hold on
axis([-1 1 -1 1])
quiver(0,0,-1,1,'k')
quiver(0,0,1,1,'k')

ax = gca;

ax.XAxisLocation = 'origin';
ax.YAxisLocation = 'origin';
```

[image]